# How can I clear this text box?

Tags: javascript, mithril.js

The following mithril code is meant to clear a text box upon pulling a value from it. It doesn't clear the text box (or do anything at all). How can I make it work?

Note that if I change this line:

```
           this.newItemName("");
```

to:

```
            this.newItemName("abc");
```

then the text box is updated with a new value. But I want To *clear* it.

```
var app = {
    controller: function() {
        this.newItemName = m.prop("");

        this.makeNewItem = function(name) {
            if (name) {
                this.newItemName("");
            }
        }
    },
    view: function(ctrl) {
        return m("div", [ m("span", "new item"),
                       m("input",
                        { type: "text",
                          onchange: m.withAttr("value", ctrl.makeNewItem.bind(ctrl)),
                          value: ctrl.newItemName() })]);
    }
};

m.module(document.body, app);
```

Comment: It works for me : http://jsfiddle.net/h89k7/1/

Comment: ok, add this answer and i'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code appears to work: http://jsfiddle.net/h89k7/1

It's possible that you are using a old version of Mithril.

Code quoted below to satisfy SO validation:

```
var app = {
controller: function () {
    this.newItemName = m.prop("");

    this.makeNewItem = function (name) {
        if (name) {
            this.newItemName("");
        }
    };
},
view: function (ctrl) {
    return m("div", [m("span", "new item"),
    m("input", {
        type: "text",
        onchange: m.withAttr("value", ctrl.makeNewItem.bind(ctrl)),
        value: ctrl.newItemName()
    })]);
}
};

m.module(document.body, app);
```

Comment: this.makeNewItem = function (name) { ... }.bind(this) may be a bit cleaner. Then you then just use m.withAttr("value", ctrl.makeNewItem) elsewhere.